# How do I delete an app from MAC OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion

when I delete this app it appears in mac App Store's update label immediately, how can i delete it thorough?
[image: free memory can't remove it]
I once removed it from two ways:
1.command + delete this app from Applications folder
2.use other app names AppCleaner to delete it
but the problem was still.

It look like some information had in system(Mac OS X 10.7.4). and App Store think it need update.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MAC OS Lion have you tried removing it from within the LaunchPad (hold icon down until it wiggles then press the x).

Alternatively try app cleaner http://appcleaner.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: Sorry just seen you tried appcleaner. Did you try to update it then remove it?

Comment: yes,I tried removed from Launchpad,and used AppCleaner, again and again it still notify to update.Yes, I update it, then remove again,problem was still

Comment: Hmm strange. Someone seems to have had the same issue but managed to solve it by reinstalling it and deleting it again http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/244708-app-store-offers-updates-deleted-app.html

Comment: thank you.I re-install/remove it several times. still not resolved the problem. I think it maybe a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on stackexchange and it worked:
I had the exact same problem and this solved it:

All app downloaded from Mac AppStore(MAS) contain a receipt inside their app bundle (example: appname.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt). MAS will scan this file to check whether the new version is available.

You can use this application (Find Any File) to search any receipt on your drive: http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/

Launch 'Find Any File' and search for: _MASReceipt
Go through each result that you think could be the culprit, copy the receipt to your desktop as a backup, and after that delete the receipt inside _MASReceipt folder.
Open MAS and let it scan for software update. If it's still showing the wrong ID, it means that you've deleted the wrong receipt. Restore the receipt backup from your desktop to it's previous location.
Repeat the process until you've found the problem receipt.

Answer (score 1):

You got options :

- You have many premium applications with GUI interface to do it for you.
- Manually remove the app from Applications folder on Mac, but this only removes the app without cleaning the associated files and folders.
- And my favorite that you can leverage UNIX shell "Terminal" to do it for you.

Find and delete the directories associated with the Application. For example:

```sh
#this will list all the paths that exist for a specific app name
$ sudo find 'location' -name 'Application'
$ rm -rf 'location'
```

A helper function:

```sh
uninstall(){
    if [ ! $@ ]; then
        echo 'you must specify a program name you want to uninstall.'
        printf "Enter an App name > \n"
        read  1
        while [[ -z $1 ]];do
            printf "Enter valid App Name >\n"
            read 1
        done
    fi
    # forcekill $1
    paths=('/Applications' $HOME) # where most installed applications lives
    echo "Scanning directories for $1 ..."
    saved_state=` for location in $paths ;do sudo find ${location} -iname "*$1*";done `
    
    if [ ${#saved_state} -gt 0 ];then
        echo "found `echo $saved_state | wc -l` dirs"
        for line in $saved_state;do echo $line 2>/dev/null| sed -l 's/ /\\ /g' |xargs rm -rf; echo "Deleting... \n$line" ;done
        echo "$1 has been removed."
    else
        echo "$1 program not found on your hard drive"
    fi

}
```

If you are not familiar with terminal program on Mac, simply open terminal app and paste uninstall function then use it by :

```
uninstall 'App name'
```

Or drop it in .bashrc or .profile and make it reusable. Assign the right app name, otherwise forced deletion will occur and you can't restore it.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

1. Drag the application from the "Applications" folder into your "Bin".
2. Go into the Bin, right-click the application and select the "Delete Immediately..." option.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to delete the apps from MacOS (Macbook M1 or any versions) is to download the AppCleaner app

https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

And drag and drop
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to delete the apps from MacOS (Macbook M1 or any versions) is to download the AppCleaner app

https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

And drag and drop the app which you want to remove from applications.

[image]

Just Click on remove and empty the trash and you are done.